# How do I take text from the text box and use it to implement it in this code?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm practicing javascript and learning on my own. I am creating a game where you enter a text coordinates and the game tells you whether you dug something up or not. But I am trying to implement a text box so you can play out of a browser instead of the command prompt, but I'm having trouble getting the game to take the text and then run the code using it when you click on the button.

Here is the HTML for the game.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Game Board</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="board.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<center>

<h1>Archaeology Board</h1>
Palace = 5 Spaces </br>
Temple = 4 Spaces </br>
Forum = 4 Spaces </br>
House = 3 Spaces </br>
Hut = 2 Spaces </br>

<h3>
<table id="board">

</table>
</h3>
<p>
<label for="DigBox">Enter dig coordinates:</label>
<input type="text" id="DigBox" size="3" value="" />
<input type="button" value="Dig" id="run" />
</p>

<p><input type="button" value="Restart Game" id="restart" /></p>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the js file to create the board.

```
function GameBoard()
{

 this.ruins = [

  { 
    name: "Palace",
    size: 5,
    successes: 0
  },

  { 
    name: "Temple",
    size: 4,
    successes: 0
  },

  { 
    name: "Forum",
    size: 4,
    successes: 0
  },

  { 
    name: "House",
    size: 3,
    successes: 0
  },

  { 
    name: "Hut",
    size: 2,
    successes: 0
  }

  ];

  this.rows = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"];
  this.columns = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];
  this.cellMarker = 'X';
}


GameBoard.prototype.setBoard = function ()
{
  var i, j, boardTags;

  boardTags = "";

  // build the first row of column labels
  boardTags += "<tr><th>&nbsp</th>";
  for (j = 0; j < this.columns.length; j++) {
    boardTags += "<th>" + this.columns[j] + "</th>";
  }
  boardTags += "</tr>";

  // build the table with HTML tags
  for (i = 0; i < this.rows.length; i++) {
    boardTags += "<tr>";
    boardTags += "<th>" + this.rows[i] + "</th>";  // row labels

    for (j = 0; j < this.columns.length; j++) {
      boardTags += "<td class='square' id='cell" + 
        this.rows[i] + this.columns[j] + "'>" + this.cellMarker + "</ td>";
    }
    boardTags += "</tr>";
  }
  $("#board").html(boardTags);


  for (i = 0; i < this.ruins.length; i++) {
    this.setRuin(this.ruins[i]);
  }
}

GameBoard.prototype.dig = function(square, processResult)
{
  var target, targetObj;
  target = $("#cell"+square).attr('ruin');
  if (target) {
    targetObj = this.getRuin(target);
    if (! $("#cell"+square).attr('dug')) {
       $("#cell"+square).attr('dug', 'yes');
       targetObj.successes++;
    }
    return targetObj;
  }
  else {
    return undefined;
  }

}

GameBoard.prototype.getRuin = function(ruinName)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < this.ruins.length; i++) {
    if (ruinName === this.ruins[i].name) {
      return this.ruins[i];
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

GameBoard.prototype.randomSquare = function()
{
   var colIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.columns.length);
   var rowIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.rows.length);
   return this.rows[rowIndex] + this.columns[colIndex];
}


GameBoard.prototype.setRuin = function(ruin)
{ 
  // keeps randomly trying to place a ruin until it fits on the board
  var candidateSquare = this.randomSquare();
  var across = Math.random() < 0.5;
  var success = this.tryPlacement(ruin, candidateSquare, across, ruin.size);
  while (! success) {
    candidateSquare = this.randomSquare();
    across = Math.random() < 0.5;
    success = this.tryPlacement(ruin, candidateSquare, across, ruin.size); 
  }
}

GameBoard.prototype.tryPlacement = function(ruin, square, across, size) {
  var nextSquare;

  if (size === 0) {
    // ruin fits!
    return true;
  }
  else if (! square) {
    // invalid square
    return false;
  }

  if (! $("#cell" + square).attr('ruin')) {
    $("#cell" + square).attr('ruin', ruin.name);

    // see if the rest of the ruin fits
    if (this.tryPlacement(ruin, this.increment(square, across), across, size - 1)) {
      // ruin fits!
      return true;
    }
    else {
      // ruin didn't fit --- undo occupied square and return false
      $("#cell" + square).removeAttr('ruin');
      return false
    }
  }
}

GameBoard.prototype.increment = function(square, across)
{
  if (across) {
    // need to increment the column dimension if possible
    var colIndex = this.columns.indexOf(square.charAt(1));
    colIndex++;
    if (colIndex === this.columns.length) {
      return undefined;
    }
    else {
      return square.charAt(0) + this.columns[colIndex];
    }
  }
  else {
    // need to increment the row dimension if possible
    var rowIndex = this.rows.indexOf(square.charAt(0));
    rowIndex++;
    if (rowIndex === this.rows.length) {
      return undefined;
    }
    else {
      return this.rows[rowIndex] + square.charAt(1);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code I'm trying to implement in

```
    $(function () {
  tryDig = function(targetCell)
  {
    var targetObj = board.dig(targetCell);

    if (targetObj) {
      alert('Success finding the ' + targetObj.name);
      $("#cell"+targetCell).html('#');
      $("#cell"+targetCell).css('color', 'blue');
    }
    else {
      alert('Failure!');
      $("#cell"+targetCell).html('*').css('color', 'red');
    }
  }


  board = new GameBoard();
  board.setBoard();


    });

    initialize = function() {
      $("#run").click(tryDig);
    }

    initialize = function() {
      $("#restart").click(GameBoard.prototype.setBoard);
    }


    $(initialize);
```

I want to make it so whatever is in the text box, the game uses that as the coordinates to dig up in the board.

Comment: Why do you define `initialize` twice?

Comment: I thought I had to in order to get both buttons to work, but I'm assuming that's incorrect?

Comment: You are overwriting the first function with the second function.

Comment: Okay, I'll take out the second function, since the first one is more important.